# Do you have to compile with Xcode 4.3.1 (or better) to have @2x images used on new iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

According to this tweet: https://twitter.com/#!/jury/status/180367953001324547

You have to compile and link with Xcode 4.3.1 against iOS SDK 5.1 in order to have the @2x retina versions of images loaded on the new iPad.

Has anyone actually verified this with real hardware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that Michael Jurewitz is an Apple evangelist, I would say that tweet is pretty authoritative.

Comment: I guess that explains the wide referencing of the tweet :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering the iPad 3 comes preloaded with iOS 5.1, I would be inclined to say yes you do need it.

Answer (score 0):

Marco Arment says [on his blog](http://www.marco.org/2012/03/16/instapaper-for-retina-ipad) that you only get the @2x graphics with iTunes 4.3.1. I believe him.